# Most efficient way to read files in Java?

Tags: java, c, file-io, performance

As most other people, I deal with file I/O a lot and I wanted to make sure that I wasn't losing time on reading the file. I currently know of FileReader() as the most efficient way to read files in Java, but I was hoping there would be something obscure that was better.

Also, can you skip reading a line in a file in Java/C?

Comment: Efficient how? Speed? Are the lines each a known length?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: Efficient in terms of speed. The lines are of a known length. The input for my code is from files and I'm trying to cut down on the running time. I have a pretty efficient algorithm, so I figured I'd try cutting down on the time taken to read the input.

Answer (score 5):

Who said FileReader is the most efficient? It isn't. Wrap a BufferedReader around it and you will get a surprise. If the file is binary you shouldn't be using a reader at all, and if efficiency is a major concern maybe you shouldn't even be using a file.

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping a BufferedReader create more system overhead?

Comment: How exactly would it do that? Buffering reduces the number of system calls. That's why we do it.